# get real-time tweets with c# without 3rd party libs

Tags: c#, twitter

I'm new to the world of  C# and TWITTER, for now I've only been coding in Java,Python,c and c++.

I'm a student and have been tasked to code a console app in C# which interacts with twitter in a real-time mode.

I need to collect and store all the tweets for a given amount of time without using a 3rd-party libs.
For now, I'm stuck with the basics .

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me start this project. provide me with sample code or a reference to a good guide that can help connect to tweeter using c# and listen to a stream of tweets by using only the API of twitter.

Comment: Did you look at their documentation?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter/tree/master/Samples/net46/CSharp/ConsoleSamples